# Grep values from nethog and netperf

Tags: linux, grep, awk

I need to monitor the network activities of a process and the bandwidth of the connection. So I decided to use `nethog` and `netperf` combine with `grep` and `awk` to write the values to a file.

`nethog` command: `nethogs -t  eth0 | grep firefox | awk '{ print $3 }'` (I want to take the upload/download speed). **The 1st problem** is that command doesn't print anything.

More detail:
command: `nethogs -t  eth0 | grep firefox` output:

```
usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000  0.338867    0.239063
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.543555    0.274219
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.794531    0.489844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.794531    0.489844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.749023    0.589844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 1.30098 3.47617
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 1.90449 8.0127
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 5.31641 25.0033
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 8.60762 42.0176
```

I want the two values at the bottom right. But as you can see the output ain't consistent (the space), add `| awk '{print $3}' most of the time return nothing`. And I can't fix this.

`netperf` command: `netperf -H 192.168.1.10` and the output is:

```
Recv   Send    Send                          
Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

524288 524288 262144    10.00    **718.62**
```

I want to print the value on the bottom right but have no idea how to. That's the **2nd problem** => solved by  fedorqui!

Can you guys help me out? Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: And what about checking the answer you were given?

Comment: Your solution works, but the first one still left...

Comment: Do you get any output of `nethogs` alone? And `nethogs -t eth0`?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. But it ain't consistent (the space between columns) so I guess that the reason... I have no idea how to fix it :(

Comment: But is what you want to output always the last field from last line?

Comment: Not really, but I try your solution on the first problem and still get nothing :(

Comment: Try to give some of the output you get. Otherwise, it is pretty complicated to know what can be the problem and how can we help.

Comment: I will update the question. Please wait a few minutes... Thank you!

Comment: So you want the values `8.60762 42.0176`? In this case, `awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF}'` does it.

Comment: It's still return nothing. I really doubt the change of the space between columns :(

Comment: You never need grep+awk since awk can do anything that grep can do. You need to show some sample output of `nethogs -t eth0` if you want a script that can parse that output as it's input along with the desired output of the tool you want to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **2nd problem**, you can do:

```
your_command | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

This will print the last field of the last line of the given input.

Comment: Since Ed Morton help me the first problem, I'm finally over these things! Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this:

```
nethogs -t eth0 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3 }'

netperf -H 192.168.1.10 | awk 'END{ print $NF }'
```

If those don't work, provide sample input to the awk scripts, expected output, and explanations.

You would need:

```
netperf -H 192.168.1.10 | awk '{v=$NF} END{ print v }'
```

with some awks since they're not required by POSIX to retain fields in the END section.

Comment: Thank you !`nethogs` command works! But `netperf `return `found`? BTW, can you please explain my command use `grep` and `awk` most of the time doesn't return anything?

Comment: fedorqui suggests me use `netperf -H 192.168.1.10 | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}' ` and I find this solution works!

Comment: If the `netperf | awk` command prints `found` then `found` is the last field on the last line of the `netperf` output as you said you wanted printed. Having said that, the `netperf | tail -1 | awk` solution will print exactly the same thing so if you're seeing a a difference in output between the 2 then you are not running the same netperf command or you have spurious control chars in it's output or there's something else you aren't telling us. Finally - yes, there are MANY ways to print the last field of the last line of input and you can employ as many tools and pipes as you like to do so.

Comment: Hi, maybe you read my question too fast :) I want `netperf` return the number at the bottom right (see the 2nd problem in my question). So the output should be `718.62` not `found`.

Comment: And I have another question? Do you see anything suspicious in my `nethog` command? Most of the time it shows nothing :(  Your `nethog` command works :)

Comment: No, I didn't read your question too fast. awk does not make up spurious words and print them. The awk command is printing the word `found` because apparently the word `found` IS the text at the bottom right of your `netperf` output, not `718.62` as you think it should be. So far you haven't shown us any output from your `nethog` command so it's impossible to guess what problem you might be having parsing it.

Comment: I updated the question for more detail of the `nethog` output. I don't understand why the bottom right of `netperf` is `found`, it supposed to be a number. `netperf -H 192.168.1.10 | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'` return the right value! Can you explain it for me?